# In Java, how to get attribute given the string with its name?

Tags: java

I'm sorry for asking this sort of questions, but I really couldn't find the answer in Google. So say I have a class with `private String myColor` and I have a string "myColor". Now  I want to manipulate the `myColor` attribute. How can I do that?

**Edit:**
Sorry for an unclear question, I guess the best way is to explain what I need it for. I've got a Swing form and want to use the preferences api to set the values of fields when loading gui. So I can read all the fields and then do `outputDirectoryTextField.setText(valueFromPrefsAPI);` for each of them, but that seems to be a bit of unneeded coding so I want to have an array(hash?) with the names of fields and loop through them, like this:

```
String[] myTextInputs = {"thisInput", "thatInput"};

for (String inputName : myTextInputs) {
    String value = prefs.get(inputName, "");
    /* some code I'm seeking to find out*/.setText(value);
}
```

Comment: Check the link from my profile page, it's made for this purpose. Using my utility you just need to do `BeanPropertyController bpc = BeanPropertyController.of(YourClass.class, ExtractionDepth.FIELDS); bpc.mutate("myColor", itsNewValue);` However do note that `ExtractionDepth.FIELDS` assumes that at least a getter exists for the field with a matching name.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use reflection to inspect the content of any object, as follows:

```
Object o = ...; // The object you want to inspect
Class<?> c = o.getClass();

Field f = c.getDeclaredField("myColor");
f.setAccessible(true);

String valueOfMyColor = (String) f.get(o);
```

Note that getDeclaredField() will only return field's declared by the object's class. If you're looking for a field that was declared by a superclass you should loop over all classes of the object (by repeatedly doing c = c.getSuperclass() until c == null)

If you want to change the value of the field you can use the set method:

```
f.set(o, "some-new-value-for-field-f-in-o")
```

Additional details: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html

---

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getField(java.lang.String)

You can use getField(...) which will search on super class if not found in class.

Comment: You'd need to explicit cast to `String` in the last line, since `Field`s aren't generic and so get() return a result of type `Object`.  You'd also need to catch various types of security exception and be aware that depending on the environment this code might not be able to run at all.  It *is* what the OP asked for but it's only responsible to let him know these things and steer him towards more appropriate alternatives.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the edit, my suggestion is to use a Map to contain a map of preference name to appropriate text field or other text component. Just build the map when you build the user interface.

```
Map<String, JTextField> guiFields = new HashMap<String, JTextField>();
```

Then you can have the code do

```
guiFields.get(inputName).setText(value);
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly... You should create public getters and setters:

```
public void setMyColor(String color) {
    this.myColor = color;
}

public String getMyColor {
    return this.myColor;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends where you want to do this. Inside the class you simply whatever with it, e.g:

```
myColor = "blah blah";
```

From outside, you need to have some public method generally as other posts indicated. In all cases, you have to be careful if your environment in multi-threaded. Class level variables are not thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

You must create a 'mutator' to modify private member variables.

```
class example{
    private string myColor;
    public void changeColor(string newColor){
        myColor = newColor;
    }
}
```

Comment: Setters and Getters would be a much more common way to do this; see Mickel's code example.

Comment: mutator is another name for a setter. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method 

>The mutator method, sometimes called a "setter"...