# Get an attribute's class from its name

Tags: java, class, reflection, dynamic, attributes

Sample not working :

```
Object o = ...; // The object you want to inspect
Class<?> c = o.getClass();

Field f = c.getDeclaredField("myColor");
f.setAccessible(true);

String valueOfMyColor = (String) f.get(o);
```

The problem in this code is that you have to cast with the String class. What I'm looking for, is to be able to find the class of an attribute from its name.

For example :

```
class Brush {
    Color myColor;
}

//Somewhere else, in a far far away galaxy
Class<?> c = getMyClassFromAttributeName("myColor");
// and c should be of type Color
```

I've tried

```
Field f = this.getClass().getDeclaredField(code);
Class<?> c1 = f.getClass(); //Gives Field 
Class<?> c2 = f.getDeclaringClass(); //Gives Brush
```

Thanks !

PS:
Used sample code from [In Java, how to get attribute given the string with its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043471/in-java-how-to-get-attribute-given-the-string-with-its-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Field.getType();`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getType%28%29).

Example:

```
Class<?> fieldType = f.getType(); //Should return Color.
```

Comment: And then how would you be able to modify it in the current object ?

Comment: @Camille R, I don't follow, please elaborate.

Comment: I was looking for a way to be able to modify the field from an "abstract" Field. and I finally found ((Color)f.get(this)).setValue(value); was working :)

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
 field.getType();
```

This works for me
( and now write this 100 times: "I will always read javadoc and look up public interfaces before asking trivial questions").

Comment: Now you must do this a 100 times: "I will **always** check my spelling **before** publishing my post on StackOverflow, especially before making remarks that will bite me in the a$$".

Answer (score 1):

Use [Field.getType()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getType%28%29).

```
Field f = Brush.class.getDeclaredField("myColor");
Class<?> c = f.getType();
```

You won't be able to use it to remove the cast from your code,  though.

Comment: Huh, We've passed Java 1.4 era (*hint*: Generics).